# How to calculate highway lengths using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, road, transportation, length

I need to create a network of highways in 8 states of the USA.

Eventually, I need their length, the speed and if possible average daily traffic volume, I don't know how to extract this information.

I am using QGIS (for the first time today), to create my map.

I already have the map, so my question is how to calculate length of roads?

Comment: ...and??? What data do you have already? Calculating length is easy...

Comment: I just started using QGIS today, I downloaded and used shapefile from TIGER, dont know what else to do :(

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As someone new my advice is to try and always focus what you ask here on a single question.  If you have not been able to find an Answer by searching this site (and elsewhere first) then I recommend that you edit your Question (there is a button beneath it) to focus it simply on how to calculate lengths first.  Describe in detail what you have done and where you are stuck.  Then you can research/ask your other question about merging roads separately.

Comment: There is no magic that will just provide you with speeds and traffic volumes. You can guess speeds from road types. There will be errors. To even guess traffic volumes you need a traffic model, not a GIS. Better would be actual counts.

Answer (score 0):

As for length:
It can be done by making the layer editable, and using the Field Calculator.

Instructions are here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html , look at points 15 and beyond in particular.

Beyond that: I'm not familiar with the datasets and what attribute data it comes with, so can't help on the other questions.